# Kdenlive: No "plus" button in tranform effect?

Tags: kdenlive

I've been using Kdenlive for a long time now, and I've upgraded it to **21.12.1 version** recently.
Now, I'm trying to do a transformation of an image, and the little "plus" button to add points for that transformation have just disappeared.
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

### Here's how it should look (taken from a tutorial video from youtube):

[image]

### And here's how mine looks:

[image: And here's how mine looks:]

**How do I add those points to do any transformation?**

Comment: Hello. This is something you may want to put a bug report in on. https://kdenlive.org/en/ Do not see it is a Ubuntu issue.

Comment: I see, thanks David!

Comment: I'd suggest upgrading your system as 20.04.3 shows you've not applied security fixes & all upgrades.  If you check out this [20.04.4](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/02/25/ubuntu-20-04-4-lts-released/) you'll see the ISO release date for 20.04.4; but installed systems upgraded to 20.04.4 more than a week before the ISO release date.  Are you really using 20.04.3? and not applying security fixes?  That may impact your issue (*unlikely but possible given you've not got all fixes applied to your system*)